# API response in useeffect with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to call products from my server with axios in my react project. I am using redux.When I have trigged the actions in component with useeffect , my products have not come but, my products have come not using useeffect.

in my component:

```
async function get(){
    await props.getProducts()
    console.log(props.products)
} 

    useEffect(() => {
        get()
    }, []);  when I  write 'get or get()' in square brackets , products loop coming to console continuous
}
```

my actions:

```
import axios from "axios"
const url="https://my-expressjs-ap.herokuapp.com/products"

export const getProducts=()=> (dispatch: (arg0: { type: any; payload: any }) => any)=>{
    axios
    .get(
      `https://my-expressjs-ap.herokuapp.com/products`
    )
    .then((response) =>
      dispatch({ type: "GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS", payload: response.data })
    )
    .catch((error) => dispatch({ type: "GET_PRODUCTS_ERROR", payload: error }));
//     fetch(url).then(res=> res.json())
//    .then(response=>dispatch(({type:"GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS",payload:response}))
//    ).catch(error=>dispatch({type:"GET_PRODUCTS_ERROR", payload:error}))
}
```

my reducers:

```
const INITIAL_STATE={
    products:[],
    message:''
}
export const reducer=(state=INITIAL_STATE,action: any)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case'GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS': return {...state, products:action.payload};
        case 'GET_PRODUCTS_ERROR': return{...state, message:action.payload}
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `props.getProducts` inside `useEffect` and set your dependency array to `[props.getProducts]`.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason your `console.log(props.products)` shows no product when you call `get()` in this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        get()
    }, []);
```

is because, the useEffect hook runs only once i.e when the component mounts, so after your api call `await props.getProducts()` via redux is complete, you don't get to see the new value because the `useEffect` hook won't run again.

Regarding this comment you in your code: ***when I  write 'get or get()' in square brackets , products loop coming to console continuous***
This happens because, every time your component renders/re-renders, a new reference of `get` is created, causing your useEffect hook to run again, which implies a new api call, which returns new results, the result which I believe are props to the component, causes another render, then a new `get` instance is created... useEffect runs again... so your are left with a infinite loop.

What you can do though is to create a memoized version of the get, and the use it as dependency in the useEffect hook i.e

```
const getProductsAsync = useCallback(async() => {
    await props.getProducts()
    console.log(props.products)
}, [props.getProducts]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProductsAsync()
    }, [getProductsAsync]);  // Now that we have this in the dep array, this hook only gets called if there a change in reference for getProductsAsync. 
}
```

I personally wouldn't do the above.
I'd just do the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProductsAsync = async() => {
        await props.getProducts()
        console.log(props.products)
    };
    getProductsAsync();
}, [props.getProducts]);
```

It's also unclear why you need the useEffect hook to log the products after a successful api call.
If you have to perform some action on the api call's result, I'd suggest you add another useEffect with the `products` as dependency in the hook's dependency array.